# Finding the derivative using Fermat's Method

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have been having trouble understanding how to calculate the derivative using Fermat's Method when it comes to various variables. For example, when given, $$ y^2 = x(8-x), $$ is there a general process that could be followed to calculate its derivative?

Comment: What do you consider Fermat's Method?  The main one I know of in this context is a theorem about maxima and minima, and while one has to calculate the derivative to _use_ the method, that calculation itself is entirely independent from the method.

Comment: As far as I know Fermat's method was for polynomials only. He took a polynomial $p$ and calculated the polynomial $p(x+h)-p(x)$, then divided by $h$ and set $h=0$. Basically it was a pre-calculus way to calculate the derivative of $p$ as a limit.

Answer (score 1):

it is $$\frac{(x+h)(8-x-h)-x(8-x)}{h}=8-h-2x$$ and the $$\lim_{h \to 0}(8-h-2x)=8-2x$$ and this is the first derivative.
Now I see that it is $y^2=x(8-x)$ so we have $$2yy'=8-2x$$ and we get $$y'=\frac{8-2x}{\pm 2\sqrt{x(8-x)}}$$